# Chinese PHP/MySQL/JSON/Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, cjk

I am currently working on an Android application which has a web-based management system attached to the content. What I want to do is display content in an Android application, which retrieves the information through JSON from the web. The application needs to support Chinese and English. Later on, I want to make German, French, Dutch and Spanish available.

My problem comes with Chinese. I have a PHP and MySQL admin system that works perfectly in English. Once I add Chinese characters in the system PHPMyAdmin does not show the characters in the same way I put them in. The encoding is wrong. From there on, retrieving everything through JSON in Android also doesn't show the right characters.

Is there anyone here who can point me in the right direction? Everything works except for Chinese. I have no experience with Chinese encoding and searched the internet. I found some things which I tried for MySQL, GB encoding the Chinese items in the database but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: standard rule: you need to maintain the SAME character set throughout the ENTIRE pipeline, or you'll get mangled text. that means all of your html pages, all of the http links, all of the server-side code, all of the code->database links, all of the database tables, etc... EVERYTHING must be consistent, or at least linked by appropriate carset conversion code. One single different charset ANYWHERE in the chain and you end up with garbage.

Comment: Use UTF-8 for everything, always. If you want to support European languages that use non-ASCII characters, choosing a GB encoding to store Chinese data is just going to make you hate yourself later.

Comment: @ wooble Thanks, but when I do this my records in PHPMYADMIN do not show the right characters. The characters become weird combinations of signs. Should I ignore how things look in PHPMYADMIN?

Comment: How did you get the data into mysql? Was it utf-8 encoded the entire way through the process?

Comment: @ wooble.  I changed my php pages to utf and gave the database records uft8_unicode_ci. When I look at PHPMYADMIN the records show weird characters as before. When I look at the json file I see weird characters as well. the json (php) is saved as utf8)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my PHP pages to UTF and gave the database records `uft8_unicode_ci`. When I look at PHPMyAdmin, the records show weird characters as before, everything looks perfect in the PHP backend. When I look at the JSON file I see weird characters as well, but different ones than PHPMyAdmin is showing. The JSON (PHP) is saved as UTF-8.

```
function loadInfo($id){
  if(is_numeric($id)){
    $locatieArray = array();
    $q = 'SELECT * FROM locaties WHERE id='.$id.'';
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    if($l = mysql_fetch_array($r)){
      $loc = array(
        'id' => utf8_encode($l['id']),
        'nameEN' => utf8_encode($l['nameEN']),
        'nameCH' => utf8_encode($l['nameCH']),
        'descEN' => utf8_encode($l['descEN']),
        'descCH' => utf8_encode($l['descCH']),
        'addEN' => utf8_encode($l['addEN']),
        'addCH' => utf8_encode($l['addCH']),
        'img' => utf8_encode($l['img']),
        'rate' => utf8_encode($l['rate']),
        'tel' => utf8_encode($l['tel']),
        'url' => utf8_encode($l['url'])
      );
    }
    $locatieArray[] = $loc;
  }
  // format array for json.
  $returnArray['locatie'] = $locatieArray;
  $json = json_encode($returnArray);
  return $json;
}
```

Is there something wrong in the way I generate the JSON or should I focus on making the Chinese characters work in PHPMyAdmin first?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I have the exact same problem.